# Man vs the gods

Tags: technology, magic

A large city with advanced technology that exceeds ours believes that it will soon be at war with a group of Greek like gods. What strategy would they use to defend themselves in case of an attack?

The gods are based on Greek mythology style of gods. They have physical form and that limits their power to line of sight. They are not omnipresent. They can not be killed. They can feel pain and be injured, but they will heal overtime. They are also at least 10 times stronger than humans.

### The gods are:

1. God of Storms: Able to manipulate wind and lightning about the same power level as Storm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Marvel_Comics)
2. Goddess of Nature: Able to control the growth of plants. She can also combine DNA from one plant and put it into another to create monstrous hybrid plants. About same power level as Swamp Thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing
3. God of the Sea: Able to bend water and control any animal that can breathe in water. He can also create hybrid animals like the Goddess of Nature. The same power level as Aquaman (new 52).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman
4. Goddess of Love: All humans that look at her fall in love with her as long as they remain within sight of her. The effects become permanent if she kisses you.
5. Goddess of the Hunt: Able to control or change her form into any land animal (insects don't count).
6. God of the Earth: Able to create earthquakes. About the same power level as Toph. http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Toph_Beifong
7. God of the Dead: Able to create and control the undead. Able to talk to ghosts. About the same power level as the nights king. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DFojKwVfq4

Remember that these gods also have many followers to call on.

### The city:

In addition to what ever technology level we have, the city had been working on some new technology.

1. Force fields: Able to protect large building from energy based attacks but not physical attacks.
2. Sonic fields: Produces a painful sonic blast affecting anyone within a half mile area not protected by special tech. Not powerful enough to kill any one, but they do cause a lot of pain.
3. Laser cannons: Very large, about the size of a small car, but powerful enough to burn off human limbs. The city has only a dozen of these canons.

Comment: "X vs Y", "Which of these are better", and "Who would win; X or Y" questions are generally too broad and opinion-based to answer reasonably. I cannot see how this could be made less broad without changing the meaning of your question, however.

Comment: @DJMEthaneMan I'm not asking who would win I'm asking what strategy City would plan on using to defend itself in case of an attack

Comment: @DJMEthaneMan asking who would win is pointless I'm not asking that. I simply want to know giving these tools what plan of the defence, would be most effective against these weapons.

Comment: Could you clarify who Storm, Toph, Nights King, Swamp Thing, and Aquaman are for people who don't follow that fandom? Links to articles outlining their powers would be helpful. Also be sure to specify which version/era of those characters. For example: Aquaman. Are we talking goofy Superfriends "talks to fish and rides a seahorse" Aquaman? Or a more modern Aquaman?

Comment: @Schwern 33 ok give me a sec

Comment: This question is too broad because there's too much going on. Defending against any one of the gods using modern technology would be its own question. Lumping seven together is too much. There's also very vague elements. "City" are we talking like Milwaukee or like New York City? The gods have "many followers"... dozens? Millions? Are they in the city? Can they infiltrate the city? That's its own question.

Comment: Yup. Way too broad. You have to realize that each God has an insane amount of mythology describing their powers, weapons, weaknesses, etc. For any defense you can dream up I can counter with Zeus morphing into your most well known politician/general, walking into your command center, and slaughtering everyone. How could people defend against that? Not very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to deal with any god that has to be physically manifested would be to entrap them.  Seal them up physically so they cannot work their powers on your civilization anymore.

For example, since their powers are limited to LOS, strikes from beyond their range would be effective to weaken them.  Once weakened (weakened is a relative term, Zeus wasn't said to be debilitated for long when Athena was born from his split skull, but he was surely wracked with pain and distracted) they would need to be encased in something that was resistant to their powers.  For example, a thick iron, steel or silver casket would be enough to do in Zeus.  If he's 10x as strong as a man, it just needs to be that much thicker, but as long as the case is grounded, he can hurl lightning bolts til his beard falls off and nothing would happen.